# Trying to Learn Scrollorama

Tags: jquery, animation, superscrollorama

I tried to learn scrollorama over the weekend, I have tried to learn and use a lot of jquery plugins in the past, never had problems with any. However this one is really confusing me a lot.

I have searched stackoverflow, and other websites about superscrollorama tutorials, however none of them specify the exact way to do it.

I have made a fiddle here for this purpose.

http://jsfiddle.net/4o46jdj7/1/

Here is what I am trying to do. The red div should pin, then the #text-1 should scroll up and fade out, after it fades out, the bottom text should scroll up and once completed, it should unpin and move on to the footer.

Here is the code I am using

```
var controller = jQuery.superscrollorama({
    triggerAtCenter: false,
    playoutAnimations: true
});

var pinAnimations = new TimelineLite();
pinAnimations
    .append(TweenMax.from(jQuery('#text-1'), .5, {css:{marginTop:'300px'}, ease: Quad.easeInOut}))
    .append(TweenMax.to(jQuery('#text-1'), .5, {css:{opacity: 1}}))
    .append(TweenMax.to(jQuery('#text-2'), .5, {css:{bottom:'30px'}}));

    controller.pin(jQuery('#member'), 600, {
        anim:pinAnimations
    });
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: huh ? What is this like a Nazi rule or what, that whatever you don't like you delete ? What substantial help did you give in this answer other than deleting my short "Thanks" and explaining to me it's not allowed? Just like my "Thanks" didn't add any meaning to the question, you should delete your comment also, coz the person looking for this answer will now see a "fantasical reply" to it now.

Comment: Bit quick with the "N"-word, aren't we. Did you read the linked article? And are you aware that youc an roll back an edit, or else edit the "Thanks" back in if you want?